# How to check a box using Microsoft Word Interop Bookmarks C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I am trying to modify a document with form fields and check boxes using C#'s Microsoft Word Interop. I've successfully managed to update the form fields using the following code, but I can't figure out how to mark a checkbox as "checked"

I created a list of items in the form that need to be updated, each form item has a `BookmarkTag` and respective data string:

```
string filename = @"C:\Users\...docx"; //removed for brevity

Application wordApp = null;
wordApp = new Application();
wordApp.Visible = false;
Document wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add(filename);

List<FormItem> formItems = new List<FormItem>
    {
        new FormItem { BookmarkTag = "author", Data = doc.Author.DisplayName },
        new FormItem { BookmarkTag = "phonenumber", Data = doc.Author.PhoneNumber },
    };

foreach(var formItem in formItems)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(formItem.Data))
    {
        Bookmark bookmark = wordDoc.Bookmarks[formItem.BookmarkTag];
        bookmark.Select();
        wordApp.Selection.TypeText(formItem.Data);
    }
}
```

Obviously this will only work with text items, but how can I identify a bookmark like "checkbox1" and mark it's value as "checked"?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with form fields it's better to address the formfield object rather than the bookmark name. The bookmark name serves as the index value for the `FormFields` collection.

For example:

```
object bookmark1 = "bkm1";
object bookmark2 = "bkm2";
wordDoc.FormFields[ref bookmark1].Result = "Text in textbox";
wordDoc.FormFields[ref bookmark2].CheckBox.Value = true;
```